# How to change the conjunction "and" in a custom bst file?

Tags: bibtex, citing, harvard-style, custom-bib

I created a custom bst file with a harvard citation style. Currently the conjunction between author names is "and".

I would like to keep "and" for text citations, ex:

- Author1 and Author2 (1999)

However, I would like to use `&` for parenthesis citations as well as in the reference list at the end.

- (Author1 & Author2, 1999)

I searched through the bst file and changed `\harvardand{}` to `\&`, this changes all "and"s to "&". How can I keep using "and" for text citations like in the first example?

I am using natbib's `\citet{}` and `\citep{}` , if that helps.
Thanks.

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}
FUNCTION {embolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bdate}
  { year empty$
      { "" }
      before.all 'output.state :=
      { year " " swap$ * "" *}
    if$
  }
FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edition" }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "volume" }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "number" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pages" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "page" }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chapter" }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Technical Report" }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {write.url}
{
  url
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ }
    { "\newline\harvardurl{" swap$ * "}" * write$ newline$ }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


STRINGS  { bibinfo}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              "," *
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "\&"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  format.names
}
FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
   "(" swap$ * ")" *
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
}
FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "\&"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\harvarditem" write$
  make.full.names duplicate$ label =
    'skip$
    { "[" label * "]" * write$ }
  if$
  "{" swap$ * "}{" * write$
  year duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "????" }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label * "}{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
      "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to ????" * warning$
       pop$ "????"
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  " \harvardyearleft " swap$ * "\harvardyearright{}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          n.dashify
        }
        {
        }
      if$
      "pages" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ": " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      {
          ": " *
      }
      if$
      swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          " " *
          get.bbl.editor
          "(" swap$ * "), " *
          * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      capitalize
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize embolden
      "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.bdate "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle embolden "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}  

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  ", "
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
  short.list key field.or.null = or
     { pop$ "" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.label}
{ calc.short.authors short.list
  'label :=
}
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" 't := }
            'skip$
          if$
          t sortify *
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}
SORT
STRINGS { last.label next.extra }
INTEGERS { last.extra.num last.extra.num.extended last.extra.num.blank number.label }
FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
  "a" chr.to.int$ #1 - 'last.extra.num.blank :=
  last.extra.num.blank 'last.extra.num.extended :=
  #0 'number.label :=
}
FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num "z" chr.to.int$ >
       { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
         last.extra.num.extended #1 + 'last.extra.num.extended :=
       }
       'skip$
      if$
      last.extra.num.extended last.extra.num.blank >
        { last.extra.num.extended int.to.chr$
          last.extra.num int.to.chr$
          * 'extra.label := }
        { last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label := }
      if$
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}
FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
  extra.label
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
  if$
  'extra.label :=
}
EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
ITERATE {forward.pass}
REVERSE {reverse.pass}
FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
  calc.short.label
}
ITERATE {bib.sort.order}
SORT
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "{\catcode`\|=0\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\@=11\catcode`\\=12" write$ newline$
  "|immediate|write|@auxout{\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\gdef\natexlab#1{#1}\fi}}"
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
```

Comment: Hello, could you show us a MWE ?

Comment: i added my bst file. I'm not sure what part to modify exactly.

Comment: For text citations change the `\&` in line 926 to `and` (however, this will change the `\citep` as well).

Comment: @jak123 is there a simple way to separate \citet{} as "and" from \citep{}  as "&" ?

Comment: I have no idea! I believe these are `natbib` commands and you might need to take a look at its documentation.